# Hola mundo con MongoDB!

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

**Objetivo:** hacer un hola mundo con MongoDB en Node.js, que consista en guardar un email y password en una BD llamada mi_bd.

**Problema:** Tengo un formulario con dos input text para el email y usuario, y cuando hago submit, el navegador devuelve *Los datos fueron guardados correctamente*, pero la consola devuelve un error: *los headers ya fueron enviados*.

**Lo que estoy haciendo:**
Cuando creo un nuevo proyecto éste viene por defecto con esta estructura:

- bin
- node_modules
- public
- routes

  - index.js
  - users.js
- views
- app.js
- npm-debug.log
- package.json

En app.js añado esto:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mi_esquema = new Schema({
  email: {type: String},
  password: {type: String}
});
var User = mongoose.model("User",mi_esquema);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mi_bd', (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
    console.log("ERROR! Imposible establecer conexión a la DB");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Conexión OK a la DB");
  }
});
```

En routes/users.js añado esto:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model("User");

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User({ email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
  user.save(function(){
    res.send("Los datos fueron guardados en la BD");
  });
});
```

Sospecho que el error de que las cabeceras ya se enviaron, es causado por la línea:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

que puse en routes/users.js. Pero si la quito, la consola me dice que mongoose no está definido, que es el mongoose de:

```
var User = mongoose.model("User")
```

Y si quito esta última línea, la consola me dice que *User* no está definido (que es el *User* declarado en la ruta).

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?

**NOTAS**

- Ya instalé MongoDB y Mongoose.
- Me he basado en [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbELfRULn1U); en el cual el árbol de carpetas es distinto al mío, así que en el tutorial la *ruta* va en app.js, y no en users.js como en mi caso.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo mas seguro esque estés usando un middleware en app.use,el que te esta arrojando esos errores pues por lo general es ello .

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué usas un middleware para un mapeo de ruta normal? Está mal hacerlo así. Los middlewares están pensados para interceptar una ruta y ejecutar código antes de ejecutar la función asociada a ella. Tu código debería verse así (aquí estoy usando [`Promesas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa) pero tú puedes seguir con callbacks si lo prefieres)

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  let { body } = req;
  User
    .create(body)
    .then((doc) => {
      // luego de crear, mongoose te devuelve el
      // documento creado por si lo necesitas
      res.jsonp({
        user: doc,
        message: 'Usuario creado'
      });
    });
});
```

Otro punto importante es que **estás guardando las contraseñas como texto plano**. Esto debes evitarlo siempre porque cualquiera que tenga acceso a la base de datos tiene acceso a las contraseñas y esto no debe ser así. Mongoose te permite crear *middlewares* o *hooks* que se ejecutarán antes o después de un suceso. Puedes aprovechar ésta característica para **hashear las contraseñas antes de guardar** el documento.

```
User.pre('save', function (next) {
  let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt);
  next();
});
```

El código anterior hashea con [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) la contraseña de todo documento `User` que vaya a ser creado.